# How to put PayPal transaction details into database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

Well I need the transaction details of paypal into my database.. example the item name, amount, etc.

here's the paypal purchase function on my controller.. I have an array there that's the one who inserts the sessioned user into my db.. but I need to insert item name and amount also..

```
public function do_purchase(){
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data['un'] = $this->session->userdata('user');


       if($data['un'] == NULL){

           redirect('error404','location');
       }

        $config['business']             = 'picturecitytest@gmail.com';
        $config['cpp_header_image']     = ''; //Image header url [750 pixels wide by 90 pixels high]
        $config['return']               = 'http://localhost/picturecity/myaccount';
        $config['cancel_return']        = 'http://localhost/picturecity/cancel_payment';
        $config['notify_url']           = 'process_payment.php'; //IPN Post
        $config['production']           = FALSE; //Its false by default and will use sandboxe
        $config["invoice"]              = random_string('numeric',8); //The invoice id

        $this->load->library('paypal',$config);

        #$this->paypal->add(<name>,<price>,<quantity>[Default 1],<code>[Optional]);

        $this->paypal->add('Party Package',2600.00,1); //First item



        $transaction = $this->paypal->pay(); //Proccess the payment

     $data = array(
        "user_id"=>$id,
    );
            $this->load->database();
            $this->db->insert('transaction', $data);
    }
```

this is the paypal library that I've downloaded

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package    CodeIgniter
 * @author      Romaldy Minaya
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011, PROTOS.
 * @license     GLP
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @version     1.0
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Paypal Class
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Payment process
 * @author      Romaldy Minaya
 *

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Documentation
    This class let you make the payment procces based on paypal API,
    effortless and easy.

*1)Use the same documentation about the vars from paypal page. http://bit.ly/j4wRR  
*2)Customize the payment procces as you desire. 
*3)Build with love. 

Implementation

*1)Copy this code in your controller's function

        $config['business']             = 'demo@demo.com';
        $config['cpp_header_image']     = ''; //Image header url [750 pixels wide by 90 pixels high]
        $config['return']               = 'sucess.php';
        $config['cancel_return']        = 'shopping.php';
        $config['notify_url']           = 'process_payment.php'; //IPN Post
        $config['production']           = TRUE; //Its false by default and will use sandbox
        $config['discount_rate_cart']   = 20; //This means 20% discount
        $config["invoice"]              = '843843'; //The invoice id

        $this->load->library('paypal',$config);

        #$this->paypal->add(<name>,<price>,<quantity>[Default 1],<code>[Optional]);

        $this->paypal->add('T-shirt',2.99,6); //First item
        $this->paypal->add('Pants',40);       //Second item
        $this->paypal->add('Blowse',10,10,'B-199-26'); //Third item with code

        $this->paypal->pay(); //Proccess the payment

    The notify url is where paypal will POST the information of the payment so you
    can save that POST directly into your DB and analize as you want.

    With $config["invoice"] is how you identify a bill and you can compare,save or update
    that value later on your DB.

    For test porpuses i do recommend to save the entire POST into your DB and analize if
    its working according to your needs before putting it in production mode. EX.

    $received_post = print_r($this->input->post(),TRUE);
    //Save that variable and analize.

    Note: html reference page http://bit.ly/j4wRR
 */
class Paypal {

    var $config         = Array();
    var $production_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';
    var $sandbox_url    = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';
    var $item           = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param   string
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct($props = array())
    {
        $this->__initialize($props);
        log_message('debug', "Paypal Class Initialized");
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * initialize Paypal preferences
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   array
     * @return  bool
     */
    function __initialize($props = array())
    {
        #Account information
        $config["business"]     = ''; //Account email or id
        $config["cmd"]          = '_cart'; //Do not modify
        $config["production"]   = FALSE;

        #Custom variable here we send the billing code-->
        $config["custom"]   = '';
        $config["invoice"]  = ''; //Code to identify the bill

        #API Configuration-->
        $config["upload"]        = '1'; //Do not modify
        $config["currency_code"] = 'PHP'; //http://bit.ly/anciiH
        $config["disp_tot"] = 'Y';

        #Page Layout -->
        $config["cpp_header_image"]         = ''; //Image header url [750 pixels wide by 90 pixels high]
        $config["cpp_cart_border_color"]    = '000'; //The HTML hex code for your principal identifying color
        $config["no_note"]  = 1; //[0,1] 0 show, 1 hide

        #Payment Page Information -->
        $config["return"]           = ''; //The URL to which PayPal redirects buyersÃ¢â‚¬â„¢ browser after they complete their payments.
        $config["cancel_return"]    = ''; //Specify a URL on your website that displays a Ã¢â‚¬Å“Payment CanceledÃ¢â‚¬Â page.
        $config["notify_url"]       = '';  //The URL to which PayPal posts information about the payment (IPN)
        $config["rm"] = '2'; //Leave this to get payment information 
        $config["lc"] = 'EN'; //Languaje [EN,ES]

        #Shipping and Misc Information -->
        $config["shipping"]     = '';
        $config["shipping2"]    = '';
        $config["handling"]     = '';
        $config["tax"]          = '';
        $config["discount_amount_cart"] = ''; //Discount amount [9.99]
        $config["discount_rate_cart"]   = ''; //Discount percentage [15]

        #Customer Information -->
        $config["first_name"]       = '';
        $config["last_name"]        = '';
        $config["address1"]         = '';
        $config["address2"]         = '';
        $config["city"]             = '';
        $config["state"]            = '';
        $config["zip"]              = '';
        $config["email"]            = '';
        $config["night_phone_a"]    = '';
        $config["night_phone_b"]    = '';
        $config["night_phone_c"]    = '';

        /*
         * Convert array elements into class variables
         */
        if (count($props) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($props as $key => $val)
            {
                $config[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    /**
     * Perform payment process
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   array
     * @return  void
     */ 
    function pay(){

        #Convert the array to url encode variables 
        $vars =  http_build_query($this->config);

        if($this->config['production'] == TRUE){
            header('LOCATION:'.$this->production_url.$vars);
        }else{
            header('LOCATION:'.$this->sandbox_url.$vars);
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    /**
     * Add a product to the list
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   array
     * @return  void
     */ 
    function add($item_name = '',$item_amount = NULL,$item_qty = NULL,$item_number = NULL){
        $this->config['item_name_'.$this->item]     = $item_name;
        $this->config['amount_'.$this->item]        = $item_amount;
        $this->config['quantity_'.$this->item]      = $item_qty;
        $this->config['item_number_'.$this->item]   = $item_number;
        $this->item++;
    }   
}
// END Paypal Class

/* End of file Paypal.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/Paypal.php */
```

please help me to get the item name and the amount.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same library. Here is my controller :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

        //send mails to user and admin(for activation) 
        $this->load->model('mails_m');
        $this->mails_m->send_user_email_after_add_website($this->session->userdata('email'));
        $this->mails_m->send_admin_email_after_add_website();

        //add website
        $last_website_id = $this->suggest_m->add_website();

        if ( $last_website_id !== '' ) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Suggested webiste has been added. Wait to be moderate.');

            // start paypal proccess
            if ( in_array($this->session->userdata('plan'), array(0,1,2,3,4,5)) ) {

                $data_plan = $this->suggest_m->get_plan_data($this->session->userdata('plan'));

                $random_key = strtotime("now").rand(1000,9999);

                $this->suggest_m->update_website_key($last_website_id, $random_key);
                $this->suggest_m->add_payment_key($last_website_id, $random_key);

                $config['business']             = 'your_email@domain.com';
                $config['return']               = site_url('suggest/pn');
                $config['cancel_return']        = site_url('suggest/pc');
                $config['notify_url']           = site_url('suggest/pv');
                $config['production']           = TRUE;

                $config["invoice"]              = $random_key;

                $this->load->library('paypal/paypal_lib',$config);

                $this->paypal_lib->add( $data_plan->name, $data_plan->price , 1, '00'.$data_plan->id);

                $this->paypal_lib->pay(); //Proccess the payment

            }else{
                redirect(base_url());
            }
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Something goes wrong. Please try again.');
            $this->load_view('suggest/edit_website/'.$id, $this->data, FALSE);
        }   
    }
```

// DEPRICATED You can  see it in action [here](http://www.pixel-promo.com/choose-plan).

Here is IPN code.

```
public function pv(){

    $this->load->library('paypal/paypal'); // Load the library
    $this->paypal->run();

    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();

    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }

    $payment_key    = $myPost["invoice"];

    if ($myPost !== '') {
        $this->suggest_m->update_payment_key($payment_key, $myPost);
        $customer_name = $myPost["first_name"].' '.$myPost["last_name"];

        //send mails
        $this->load->model('mails_m');
        $this->mails_m->send_user_email_after_payment($myPost["payer_email"]);
        $this->mails_m->send_admin_email_after_payment($myPost["payer_email"], $customer_name);


        // calculate item_id
        $item_id = ltrim($myPost['item_number1'], '0');
        switch ($item_id) {
            case '1':
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $expire = strtotime( $date . ' +999 year');
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expire);
                $status = 0;
                $payed  = 1;
                 $this->suggest_m->update_website_data($status, $payed, $expire, $payment_key);
                break;
            case '2':
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $expire = strtotime( $date . ' +999 year');
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expire);
                $status = 0;
                $payed  = 1;
                 $this->suggest_m->update_website_data($status, $payed, $expire, $payment_key);
                break;
            case '3':
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $expire = strtotime( $date . ' +999 year');
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expire);
                $status = 0;
                $payed  = 1;
                 $this->suggest_m->update_website_data($status, $payed, $expire, $payment_key);
                break;
            case '4':
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $expire = strtotime( $date . ' +1 year');
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expire);
                $status = 0;
                $payed  = 1;
                 $this->suggest_m->update_website_data($status, $payed, $expire, $payment_key);
                break;
            case '5':
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $expire = strtotime( $date . ' +1 year');
                $expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expire);
                $status = 0;
                $payed  = 1;
                 $this->suggest_m->update_website_data($status, $payed, $expire, $payment_key);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Of cource you must setup ipn url in your paypal account in my case is www.domain.com/controller_name/pv () like the funntion above.

ALso you need en extra library for IPN. HERE is my IPN simple library. Load this in IPN Method

```
    <?php
class Paypal
{ 
    /*
     * 'live' or 'sandbox'
    */
    public function __construct($mode = 'sandbox') {

        if ($mode == 'live') {
            $this->_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $this->_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }
    }

    public function run() {

        $postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $postFields .= '&' . $key . '='.urlencode($value);
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(

            CURLOPT_URL             => $this->_url, 
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => FALSE,
            CURLOPT_POST            => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $postFields,

            ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```